# Using XML in sub datasets

Tags: xml, dataset, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm new to **iReport** Designer 5.0.1 and I'm having trouble creating and using **sub datasets**.
The **XML** file has just a list of `<incidence>`'s. For each `<incidence>` I want to show a TimeSeries Chart using the childs of `<sonometria>`. 
This is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<incidencias>
    <incidencia id="1">
        <sonometria>
            <lectura>
                <fecha>1361780123891</fecha>
                <lmax>80.0</lmax>
                <leq>68</leq>
                <l10>72</l10>
                <l90>62</l90>
                <limite>90</limite>
            </lectura>
            <lectura>
                <fecha>1361780125994</fecha>
                <lmax>82.0</lmax>
                <leq>70</leq>
                <l10>73</l10>
                <l90>65</l90>
                <limite>90</limite>
            </lectura>
            <lectura>
                <fecha>1361780127030</fecha>
                <lmax>85.0</lmax>
                <leq>69</leq>
                <l10>71</l10>
                <l90>62</l90>
                <limite>90</limite>
            </lectura>
        </sonometria>
    </incidencia>
    <incidencia id="2">
        <sonometria>
            <lectura>
                <fecha>1361780130155</fecha>
                <lmax>85.0</lmax>
                <leq>75</leq>
                <l10>78</l10>
                <l90>66</l90>
                <limite>90</limite>
            </lectura>
            <lectura>
                <fecha>1361780131191</fecha>
                <lmax>82.0</lmax>
                <leq>70</leq>
                <l10>73</l10>
                <l90>65</l90>
                <limite>90</limite>
            </lectura>
            <lectura>
                <fecha>1361780132289</fecha>
                <lmax>80.0</lmax>
                <leq>65</leq>
                <l10>70</l10>
                <l90>60</l90>
                <limite>90</limite>
            </lectura>
        </sonometria>
    </incidencia>
</incidencias>
```

The main query is: `/incidencias/incidencia`
The sub dataset query is: `/incidencias/incidencia[@id="1"]/sonometria/lectura`. Yeah, `id="1"` is not going to be very dynamic but that's a different problem I don't want to face yet.

Well, the problem is that the charts are empty:
[image]
So I don't know if the problem is the sub dataset or the chart that uses the dataset. Here it is my template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="incidencias" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="71bf8975-c38f-430a-9743-8924d800c8fc">
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="c141c224-fb9f-4de3-851a-ab362f2b336b">
        <queryString language="xPath">
            <![CDATA[/incidencias/incidencia[@id="1"]/sonometria/lectura]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="fecha" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fecha]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="lmax" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lmax]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="l10" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[l10]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="leq" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[leq]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="l90" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[l90]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="limite" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[limite]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ancestor::incidencia/@id]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Alfonso\\Desktop\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/incidencias/incidencia]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="52" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="de49d5f3-fbc4-4922-aedf-a1ad48b3f8d0" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="52"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="24" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Incidencias]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e8fb4f62-e0b6-43a2-b502-d2482b718097" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[@id]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="162" splitType="Stretch">
            <timeSeriesChart>
                <chart>
                    <reportElement uuid="2b58dfb5-85f8-4e5e-bc5d-32f2f14b3503" x="0" y="23" width="555" height="130"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="Second">
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="4a8bc785-e943-4de6-b9cf-a47149a1a3ed"/>
                    </dataset>
                    <timeSeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Ejemplo"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <timePeriodExpression><![CDATA[new Date($F{fecha})]]></timePeriodExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[Float.parseFloat($F{lmax})]]></valueExpression>
                    </timeSeries>
                </timeSeriesDataset>
                <timeSeriesPlot>
                    <plot/>
                </timeSeriesPlot>
            </timeSeriesChart>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="7c330739-e9a2-4879-9410-7b61589fd89e" x="0" y="3" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK charts can be placed only into summary band of report. You can't make some charts for one report by using subdataset. 
Try to change your report with using subreport for lectura (xPath query like "//lectura"). In subreport you must to place chart in summary band.

Comment: So subreports and subdatasets are not so similar. Well, I will try with subreports and see what happens. thanks for your help, I will accept/vote tomorrow

Comment: It seems you are right, and it is easier with subreports. I have been testing and I think I can achieve what I want with subreports. Thanks!